# awk filter rows based on date condition

Tags: shell, awk

I have a large dataset for analysis and I am looking for shell scripting to filter the rows only to what I require, so I am able to load the dataset for further analysis in R.

The structure for data is as follows:

```
Size,ModifiedTime,AccessTime,contentid
4886,"Jun 11, 2009 06:51:08 PM","Mar 15, 2013 09:24:53 AM",000000285b7925f511b3159a72f80a4a
4096,"Aug 21, 2008 03:54:28 PM","May 12, 2009 04:45:41 PM",0000011afae4d1227c4df57b410ea52c
84848,"Feb 12, 2007 12:40:00 PM","Apr 07, 2014 09:39:03 AM",000001cec02017ca3eb81ddc4cd1c9ff
518,"Aug 22, 2006 02:12:03 PM","Dec 25, 2007 06:48:18 AM",00000233565d1c17c3135a9504c455ca
264158,"Dec 08, 2009 03:28:14 PM","Apr 08, 2013 11:52:15 AM",000003020ba74b9d1b6075d3c1b8fcb3
725963,"Sep 29, 2008 03:45:21 PM","May 17, 2011 08:48:40 AM",0000034b98d29d84ce7b61ee68be7658
1340,"Sep 07, 2011 03:36:54 AM","Mar 12, 2013 02:55:01 AM",000004ed899e26ae1c9b1ece35a98af1
75264,"Jul 28, 2011 05:09:58 PM","Jun 07, 2014 04:21:28 PM",000005a09fd2eb706c5800eb06084160
198724,"Jul 23, 2012 02:25:58 PM","Jan 21, 2013 12:58:07 PM",0000060b9d552c35f281b5033dcfa1b4
```

It is essentially a large csv file.

Now I want to filter rows for which `AccessTime` is less than 10 years and then write it into a separate csv file, which in this case should print 2nd row (excluding header)

I tried the following: create a temp time variable and compare with the `AccessTime`, if it's less then print row.

```
BEGIN{
    FPAT = "([^,]+)|(\"[^\"]+\")"; #this to read csv as some column value contains ,
    OFS=",";
    date=$(date -d "-3650 days" +"%s"); #temp time variable in epoch format
}
{
    command="date -d" $6 " +%s"; #$6 refers to AccessTime column
    ( command | getline temp );  #converts Accesstime value to epoch format
    close(command);
    if(temp<date) print $6
}
```

But when I run this command, it doesn't print anything.
Any help is much appreciated.

Desired output:

```
Size,ModifiedTime,AccessTime,contentid
4096,"Aug 21, 2008 03:54:28 PM","May 12, 2009 04:45:41 PM",0000011afae4d1227c4df57b410ea52c
518,"Aug 22, 2006 02:12:03 PM","Dec 25, 2007 06:48:18 AM",00000233565d1c17c3135a9504c455ca
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU awk for time functions, FPAT, and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS  = ","
    FPAT = "([^" OFS "]*)|(\"[^\"]+\")"
    now  = strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S")
    year = gensub(/ .*/,"",1,now)
    rest = gensub(/[^ ]+/,"",1,now)
    secs = mktime((year-10) rest)
    thresh = strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S",secs)
}
NR > 1 {
    split($3,t,/[ ,:]+/)
    mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",t[1])+2)/3
    hour  = t[4] + ( (t[7] == "PM") && (t[4] < 12) ? 12 : 0 )
    curr  = sprintf("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d", t[3], mthNr, t[2], hour, t[5], t[6])
}
(NR == 1) || (curr < thresh)
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Size,ModifiedTime,AccessTime,contentid
4096,"Aug 21, 2008 03:54:28 PM","May 12, 2009 04:45:41 PM",0000011afae4d1227c4df57b410ea52c
518,"Aug 22, 2006 02:12:03 PM","Dec 25, 2007 06:48:18 AM",00000233565d1c17c3135a9504c455ca
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @EdMorton, your solution perfectly works. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    m["Jan"]="01"                                     # lookups for months
    m["Feb"]="02"                                     # Feb -> 02
    m["Mar"]="03"                                     # Mar -> 03
    m["Apr"]="04"                                     # etc.
    m["May"]="05"
    m["Jun"]="06"
    m["Jul"]="07"
    m["Aug"]="08"
    m["Sep"]="09"
    m["Oct"]="10"
    m["Nov"]="11"                                     # below we get todays date
    m["Dec"]="12"                                     # 10 years ago

    dcmd="date +\"%Y%m%d,\" --date=\"10 years ago\""  # returns 20101204,
    if((dcmd | getline d)<=0)                         # if getline fails
        exit 1                                        # exit

    # d=strftime("%Y%m%d")-10^5 ","                   # use this for GNU awk
}
$9 m[$7] $8>=d' file                                  # explained below
```

`d` gets value `20101204.` (notice the trailing comma) from the `date +"%Y%m%d," --date="10 years ago"`. Reading the AccessTime from the file and rearranging the components with `$9 m[$7] $8`, for example, for `Mar 15, 2013` is `20130315,` (notice the comma again). The condition is the comparison of those two dates.

Output:

```
4886    Jun 11, 2009 06:51:08 PM        Mar 15, 2013 09:24:53 AM        000000285b7925f511b3159a72f80a4a
84848   Feb 12, 2007 12:40:00 PM        Apr 07, 2014 09:39:03 AM        000001cec02017ca3eb81ddc4cd1c9ff
264158  Dec 08, 2009 03:28:14 PM        Apr 08, 2013 11:52:15 AM        000003020ba74b9d1b6075d3c1b8fcb3
725963  Sep 29, 2008 03:45:21 PM        May 17, 2011 08:48:40 AM        0000034b98d29d84ce7b61ee68be7658
1340    Sep 07, 2011 03:36:54 AM        Mar 12, 2013 02:55:01 AM        000004ed899e26ae1c9b1ece35a98af1
75264   Jul 28, 2011 05:09:58 PM        Jun 07, 2014 04:21:28 PM        000005a09fd2eb706c5800eb06084160
198724  Jul 23, 2012 02:25:58 PM        Jan 21, 2013 12:58:07 PM        0000060b9d552c35f281b5033dcfa1b4
```

Comment: could you please explain your code, I am sorry I am a beginner in awk and having difficult time to understand the code?

Comment: Thanks a lot @James Brown

Comment: Hi James, the date command works without rearranging the components. could you please review my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your shown samples, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`. Also considering that you need to compare your 2nd occurrence of date with current date. Also this solution is not dealing with leap seconds concept(trying to figure out another way too here).

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  num=split("jan,feb,mar,apr,may,jun,jul,aug,sept,oct,nov,dec",arr1,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    month[arr1[i]]=sprintf("%02d",i)
  }
}
match($0,/[AP]M.*[AP]M/){
  val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/^[AP]M +/,"",val)
  sub(/ [AP]M +$/,"",val)
  split(val,array,"[ ,]")
  dat=array[4] OFS month[tolower(array[1])] OFS array[2] OFS array[5]
  timE=(systime()-mktime(gensub(/[ ":-]/," ","g",dat)))/(365*60*24*60)
  if(timE>10){ print }
}
' Input_file
```

This will not print header in case you need to print it then add `FNR==1{print;next}` before `match` function.

Answer (score 1):

Another shorter awk solution.

```
$ awk -F, -v ct=$(date "+%s") ' NR>1 { dc="date -d"$4 $5 " \"+%s\""; dc|getline t;  yrs=(ct - t)/(24*60*60*365) }  yrs>10 || NR==1 ' monte.txt
Size,ModifiedTime,AccessTime,contentid
4096,"Aug 21, 2008 03:54:28 PM","May 12, 2009 04:45:41 PM",0000011afae4d1227c4df57b410ea52c
518,"Aug 22, 2006 02:12:03 PM","Dec 25, 2007 06:48:18 AM",00000233565d1c17c3135a9504c455ca
$
```

Explanation:

The date command works if we just pass the string representation of access time.

```
$ date -d"Jun 11, 2009 06:51:08 PM"
Thu Jun 11 18:51:08 IST 2009
```

It works even without the comma

```
$ date -d"Jun 11 2009 06:51:08 PM"
Thu Jun 11 18:51:08 IST 2009
```

So there is no need to clean the data. Just passing $4 and $5 from the input file with comma as delimiter would work.

For comparison, I have used the epoch

```
awk -F, -v ct=$(date "+%s") '           #get the current epoch seconds via ct
NR>1 { 
       dc="date -d"$4 $5 " \"+%s\"";    #build the date command using access time $4 and %5
       dc|getline t;                    #execute the command and get the output in temp t
       yrs=(ct - t)/(24*60*60*365)      #calcualte the number of years between ct and t
 }  

 yrs>10 || NR==1                         #print if diff yrs > 10 or NR==1 for header
'
```

**Another solution:**

If you want to apply the logic for 10 years in the date command, then we need to just remove the double quotes from the $5.

```
$ awk -F, -v ct=$(date "+%s") ' NR>1 { c5=substr($5,1,length($5)-1);dc="date -d"$4 c5 " + 10 years \" \"+%s\""; dc|getline t } t<ct  ' monte.txt
Size,ModifiedTime,AccessTime,contentid
4096,"Aug 21, 2008 03:54:28 PM","May 12, 2009 04:45:41 PM",0000011afae4d1227c4df57b410ea52c
518,"Aug 22, 2006 02:12:03 PM","Dec 25, 2007 06:48:18 AM",00000233565d1c17c3135a9504c455ca
$
```